# Using switch statement to show pictures in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to make the image1 visible when it is Sunday, image2 visible when it is Monday, and so on, using the switch statement in Javascript. How do i do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display what day it is today.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var x;
    var d=new Date().getDay();
    switch (d)
    {
        case 0:
            x="Today it's Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            x="Today it's Monday";
            break;
        case 2:
            x="Today it's Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            x="Today it's Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            x="Today it's Thursday";
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

<img src="image1.png" id="one"style="visibility:Hidden"/>
<img src="image2.png" id="one"style="visibility:Hidden"/>
<img src="image3.png" id="one"style="visibility:Hidden"/>
<img src="image4.png" id="one"style="visibility:Hidden"/>
<img src="image5.png" id="one"style="visibility:Hidden"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should not use the same id `one` on all your images

Comment: but how to make it visible from switch after i change all the ids to different?

Comment: use `class` instead if `id`

Comment: Aside from the `id` issue, what is actually the problem? Your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5x5P/) works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having five `<img>` elements, you can have one then simply change its src according to the day value.

HTML Markup

```
<img id='dayImage'/>
```

Javascript

```
var d = new Date().getDay()
var dayImg = document.getElementById('dayImage');
dayImg.src = "image"+d+".png";
```

**Update**

If you still need to have five separate images you will need a way to identify each image. As it stands all your images have the same `id` attribute so you will first need to fix this.

Assuming you change your markup to something like this:

```
<img src="image1.png" id="dayImg0" style="visibility:hidden"/>
<img src="image2.png" id="dayImg1" style="visibility:hidden"/>
<img src="image2.png" id="dayImg2" style="visibility:hidden"/>
...
```

You could then display the appropriate image like this

```
var d = new Date().getDay()
var dayImg = document.getElementById('dayImg'+d);
dayImg.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: five images are different from each other and is place in different positions.

Answer (score 0):

- first, give your images different id's like `zero`, `one`, ..., `four`
- use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden`, because display-none not reserves it's required space

see this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/bJXmt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly modify the HTML page, to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display what day it is today.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var x;
    var d=new Date().getDay();
    switch (d)
    {
        case 0:
            x="Today it's Sunday";
            document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
            break;
        case 1:
            x="Today it's Monday";
            document.getElementById("two").style.display="block";
            break;
        case 2:
            x="Today it's Tuesday";
            document.getElementById("three").style.display="block";
            break;
        case 3:
            x="Today it's Wednesday";
            document.getElementById("four").style.display="block";
            break;
        case 4:
            x="Today it's Thursday";
            document.getElementById("five").style.display="block";
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

<img src="image1.png" id="one" style="display:none"/>
<img src="image2.png" id="two" style="display:none"/>
<img src="image3.png" id="three" style="display:none"/>
<img src="image4.png" id="four" style="display:none"/>
<img src="image5.png" id="five" style="display:none"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript getDay() function returns 0 for sunday (see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) you dont need to mess around with the indexes, just use a simple for loop like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<body>
    <p>Click the button to display what day it is today.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x;
            var d = new Date().getDay();
            switch (d) {
                case 0:
                    x = "Today it's Sunday";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    x = "Today it's Monday";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x = "Today it's Tuesday";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x = "Today it's Wednesday";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x = "Today it's Thursday";
                    break;
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
            images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                if (i != d) {
                    images[i].style.visibility = 'Hidden';
                } else {
                    images[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <img src="image1.png" id="one" style="visibility:Hidden" />
    <img src="image2.png" id="one" style="visibility:Hidden" />
    <img src="image3.png" id="one" style="visibility:Hidden" />
    <img src="image4.png" id="one" style="visibility:Hidden" />
    <img src="image5.png" id="one" style="visibility:Hidden" />
</body>
```